# How can I fix the Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile with Java?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

When I open my Minecraft Server I am often meet with the same error:

> "Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\NewMinecraft\minecraft_server 1.4_01.jar"

[image: Image of Error]

Comment: Can you define "open my Minecraft Server"? How are you opening it? Do you have a script that's executing the jar file or are you simply double clicking the jar file on say your desktop or file explorer?

Answer (score 2):

Given the information, there's a few things you can try:

1. Re-download the .jar file, there's a chance the one you have is corrupted. I'm not too well versed on Minecraft (server) versions, but there's a chance yours is outdated (though you may be doing that on purpose)
2. Confirm java version, via command line, and make sure it's up to date. Open a command prompt and type the following command. You may need to update java and make sure it's set correctly in your System Environment's PATH variable.

```
java -version
```

3. Try executing the .jar file from command line (that is, open a command prompt and navigate to the folder containing the server .jar file via this command:

```
cd  C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\NewMinecraft
```

and then execute the jar file with this command: **NOTE:** you should be able to press <kbd>TAB</kbd> after typing a few charachters of the .jar file for it to autofill.

```
java -jar .\minecraft_server 1.4_01.jar
```

Also not sure how much it matters, but in your screenshot, it looks like a space in between minecraft_server and the version number, try removing this space or replace it with an <kbd>_</kbd> or <kbd>.</kbd>.

Without more details of the actual error in hand, it's hard to propose a concrete solution, but hopefully these troubleshooting recommendations can aid you in finding the root issue. My hunch is the java version.